# Apply over data frame subset causing duplicates / replicates

Tags: r, subset, apply, na

I am trying to find the observations corresponding to NA values for each column/feature. I have replicated the issue with a much smaller data set.

```
whichNA <- function(vec) {
  which(is.na(vec))
}
orgnl <- data.frame("x" = c(3,6,NA,12,NA,18),"y" = c(NA,NA,6,8,10,NA))
subs = orgnl[-c(2:3),]
rownames(subs) = as.character(1:nrow(subs))
apply(subs,2,whichNA)
```

Output:

```
$x    
3     
3     
$y    
1 4     
1 4
```

Expected Output:

```
$x   
3     
$y    
1 4
```

Comment: Use `sapply(subs,whichNA)`

Comment: I really never would have guessed that. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @arg0naut91 In my opinion, that is answer-worthy, probably including Joran's explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
sapply(subs, whichNA)
```

Giving:

```
$x
[1] 3

$y
[1] 1 4
```

As noted by @joran, in your output there are actually no duplicates - the difference is only that using `apply` with your function produces named integers.

For instance, you can check it for the `x` vector by:

```
attr(apply(subs, 2, whichNA)$x, 'names')

[1] "3"
```

While in the case of `sapply` this attribute is `NULL`:

```
attr(sapply(subs, whichNA)$x, 'names')

NULL
```

As suggested by @joran, amending the function would work as well:

```
whichNA <- function(vec) {
  unname(which(is.na(vec)))
}

apply(subs, 2, whichNA)

$x
[1] 3

$y
[1] 1 4
```